# How to move browser's scrollbar to a class?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This script loads 10 more posts from peoples.php in index.php every time the button is pressed (through the loadfeed function).

```
$("#loadmore").click(function() {
    cap += 10;
    loadfeed();
    $(this).addClass("loading");
    that = this
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(that).removeClass('loading');
    }, 3000)
});
```

My posts are in this format and the class in number ASC, using `$i` for every post. The class has nothing to do with my CSS, I added it now to explain my thought.

```
<div id="post" class="p1"></div>
<div id="post" class="p2"></div>
<div id="post" class="p3"></div>
.
.
.
```

Every click on "load more" loads +10 posts. When a user enters in the page there is a default of 20 posts.

This is how I add 10 posts.

```
...   .load('people.php?cap='+cap, function () { ...
```

When I click on "load more" I want the scrollbar to be in a predefined position and not at the end of the page as it does now.

I tried to use  in some places of the index.php but it is not ideal, not working as I want it.

So when a user clicks "load more" at first, the posts loaded are 30 from the default 20. On second click are made 40. For now, the last post shown is the 20th, 30th, 40th....

How can I take the browser to the 21st, 31st, 41st post when the use clicks on `#loadmore` ?

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

Comment: _In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); **they cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F"._  [CSS Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters)

Comment: I wouldn't bother with a plugin. You can use something like `$('body').scrollTop($('.p1').offset().top)`.

Comment: @MichaelMior I want this to moved after the loadfeed() is completed. I updated my question with this function

Comment: So you can put that in the callback for the `load` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly each my must appear only once in each document. But classes can be affected to multiple elements and each element can own multiple classes.

And theire is two solutions :
1 - pure html

```
<a href="#anchorid">go to title</a>
<!-- html code -->
<h1 id="anchorid">title</h1>
```

2 - jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
         // here using jquery scroll plugin
    });
});


<a href="">go to title</a>
<!-- html code -->
<h1 id="anchorid">title</h1>
```

Comment: How to make use of the scroll plugin? I am accepting these if you complete the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery plugin [`scrollTo()`](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/).

Comment: How do I scroll in 21,31,41, i mean is there a function that fullfill them all ? I tried to bind `animate scrollTop` but I lost the class effect.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, something like:

```
window.scrollTo(0, $('#id-of-21st-element').offset()[1])
```

The key bits are window.scrollTo() and jquery's offset()